# Is there a way to have website admins without having regular accounts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication

I want to be able to have a couple of people with admin rights so that they can edit text fields and other things, but I don't want there to be a login button because there's no rights that I can give to "regular" users, so is there any way I can either secretly have a login or any other solution that I'm just not thinking of.. I'm using .NET with C# in code behind in case that's relevant.

Comment: Just create a login page and don't put a link to it on your site.

Comment: This is software. Anything is possible™

Comment: Yeaa, the hidden login page was something I was considering but hoping not to have to do, but if that's what it is then so be it, thanks!

Comment: What's the difference between an admin and a regular account if a regular account does not exist? (That was leading question. There is no difference; your "regular" users just happen to have admin-like privileges.)

Comment: What is the environment... is this a closed application or open to the public?

Comment: secret login page or login link... those are pretty much your options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends... If you're on intranet, you can use other forms of authentication, for instance automatic windows/AD authentication. Also you can authenticate users based on their IP address, but that would require them to have public static IP, which is not always possible or desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done sometimes if its a closed environment (like an application on an intranet).

On any page that needs special rights:

Have the code check a table for a list of allowed users (using their windows username from their currently logged in Windows Acct). I would do something like this in the page load: (pseudo code)

```
If NOT userallowed
     Send message to the user that he is not allowed
Else
     Do whatever code is required
```

the `userallowed` function would just return a boolean if the windows id was in the table